# Issue with History Archive - second node not syncing with the first

Tags: stellar-core, history

I ran second node but it's not reaching consensus with the first node. I think second node will sync up with the first node with History Archive. 
I ran the second node but it's giving 'Lost track of consensus' as shown below:

```
2020-01-30T15:24:22.235 GBHXW [Herder WARNING] Lost track of consensus

2020-01-30T15:24:22.235 GBHXW [Herder WARNING] Out of sync context: {

   "queue" : null,

   "scp" : {

      "47" : {

         "ballotProtocol" : {

            "ballot" : "(4294967295,[  txH: 797db3, ct: 1580378020, 
upgrades: [ ] ])",

            "heard" : false,

            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",

            "state" : "i: 47 | EXTERNALIZE | b: (4294967295,[  txH: 797db3, 

ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]) | p: (4294967295,[  txH: 797db3, ct: 

1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]) | p': (<null_ballot>) | h: (1,[  txH: 797db3, 

ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]) | c: (1,[  txH: 797db3, ct: 1580378020, 

upgrades: [ ] ]) | M: 1"

         },

         "nomination" : {

            "X" : [ "[  txH: 797db3, ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]" ],

            "Y" : [ "[  txH: 797db3, ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]" ],

            "roundnumber" : 0,

            "started" : false

         },

         "quorum_sets" : {

            "b81b69" : {

               "t" : 1,

               "v" : [ "Node2" ]

            }

         },

         "statements" : [

            [

               1580378027,

               "{ENV@Node2 |  i: 47 | NOMINATE | D: b81b69 | X: {'[  txH: 

797db3, ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]'} | Y: {'[  txH: 797db3, ct: 

1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]'} }",

               true
            ],

            [

               1580378027,

               "{ENV@Node2 |  i: 47 | EXTERNALIZE | c: (1,[  txH: 797db3, 

ct: 1580378020, upgrades: [ ] ]) | h.n: 1 | (lastD): b81b69 }",

               true

            ]

         ],

         "validated" : true

      }

   },

   "you" : "Node2"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem with the history archive is solved Right Now.
I have added the following properties in the config file which are given below

```
**KNOWN_PEERS=[
  "127.0.0.1:11626",
  "127.0.0.1:11726",
  "127.0.0.1:11526"
  ]
  
 PREFERRED_PEERS=[
  "127.0.0.1:11626",
  "127.0.0.1:11726",
  "127.0.0.1:11526"
  ]
 
PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS =[
"GBHXIWKOEHLGYLNHBKHRGGASYJ4E6IGUNPROKZ5SATAGF67N5WUS5ORKO",
"GIBXFIPZUIZEAMNLEN5M23GJISRDEO2TJ5W6O272URALYNFEFRHYEALT5V",
"GIBU3I2QOHIX2XUNVTYO3LFUE5LJICWTQQPHL3IET2EOXE3M4J737D6YO"
]
NODE_NAMES = [
 "GBHXIWKOEHLGYLNHBKHRGGASYJ4E6IGUNPROKZ5SATAGF67N5WUS5ORKO Node02",
 "GIBXFIPZUIZEAMNLEN5M23GJISRDEO2TJ5W6O272URALYNFEFRHYEALT5V Node03",
 "GIBU3I2QOHIX2XUNVTYO3LFUE5LJICWTQQPHL3IET2EOXE3M4J737D6YO Node01"
 ]
  
 [QUORUM_SET]
 THRESHOLD_PERCENT=50
 VALIDATORS=["$Node04","$Node02","$Node03","$Node01"]
  
 [HISTORY.local]
 get="cp /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node4/vs/{0} {1}"
 put="cp {0} /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node4/vs/{1}"
 mkdir="mkdir -p /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node4/vs/{0}"
  
 [HISTORY.node01]
 get="cp /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node1/vs/{0} {1}"
  
 [HISTORY.node02]
 get="cp /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node2/vs/{0} {1}"
  
 [HISTORY.node03]
 get="cp /home/sayoojmandodi/history/node3/vs/{0} {1}"**
```

---

History Archive Structure is as written Below

1. Each and every node will be storing history archive to there own corresponding location
2. Each node will get the history archive from all other nodes as shown in the above config.

---

Commands to be executed First time when a node is starting

- List item

If quorum(sync)is not met in the node. Start with forcescp

- List item

  If quorum exist then try to catchup the archive. command is ./stellar-core catcup current/max
- List item

  Make sure ledger count is update from the log.
- List item

  start the core ./stellar-core.